# C Programming in Visual Studio - Go To Definition Descriptions

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find C function descriptions or definition bodies using Visual Studio.  When I go to definition, it takes me to the header declaration which isn't very useful.  Sure I can see the signature but that's not much.  If I go to the definition in the header file, it doesn't take me to the source code where the comments/body may be.  Anyone know how to get more info within VS?

[image: Before GoTo]

[image]

Comment: that all depends on how you are linking against the std libraries. some might not have source for you to look at.\

Comment: I'm using the C/C++ extension and haven't tweaked any settings. I've probably checked functions across 3 or 4 libraries and all seem to look the same. Do you have a reference for what you think I need to do?

Comment: You are linking against static/dynamic libraries. The source is compiled and you get a header. That's your "definition". There is no way to see in the IDE what you are asking for. If I find a method in the CRT that I want to see the source code to, I google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot get the source code directly from your system/PC because the library files are first compiled and then stored as .a(Unix) or .lib(Windows) static files / .so(Unix) or .dll(Windows) dynamic files.
*Note: Similar answer is mentioned in the comment section as well by others.*

However, you can download the source codes of various implementations. For starter, you can go to [GLIBC](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html) and download the source code from there. Instructions to download are mentioned on the website itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is an index to a list of detailed function descriptions, discussion, and in some cases example code in the Microsoft [alphabetical function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crt-alphabetical-function-reference?view=vs-2019).

This is surely of much more practical use than looking at the source code to find out what the library functions do.